# Select all records from one table with extra field that shows if that record was found in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

users:

```
ID      CUSTOMID     NAME
1       X543         John
2       X354         Jane
3       X389         Jack
4       X123         James
```

list:

```
ID      CUSTOMID     NAME       ADDRESS
1       X543         John       address1
2       X543         John       address2
3       X543         John       address3
4       X543         John       address4
5       X543         John       address5
6       X354         Jane       address1
7       X354         Jane       address2
8       X354         Jane       address3
9       X389         Jack       address1
10      X389         Jack       address2
11      X389         Jack       address3
12      X389         Jack       address4
13      X389         Jack       address5
14      X389         Jack       address6
```

I need the following result:

```
ID      CUSTOMID     NAME     MATCHED
1       X543         John     1
2       X354         Jane     1
3       X389         Jack     1
4       X123         James    0
```

If there's a CUSTOMID in the list table then I need identifier added to the users table. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT users.*, if(list.CUSTOMID IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE) AS matched from users LEFT JOIN list ON (users.CUSTOMID=list.CUSTOMID)
```

But I'm getting a lot of duplicates since there are multiple records in the list table with the same CUSTOMID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CASE and EXISTS

```
Select u.*, 
  case when exists (
    select 1 from list l where u.customid =l.customid
  ) then 1 else 0 end matched
From users u;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your existing query only very slightly...

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
              , COALESCE(l.CUSTOMID IS NOT NULL,0) matched 
           FROM users u
           LEFT 
           JOIN list l
             ON l.CUSTOMID = u.CUSTOMID
```

Comment: Thanks for modifying it. It works, but taking a lot longer to run a query.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use GROUP_ BY statement, so you don't have duplicates, you should group for customID in both tables.
However you can also use keyword DISTINCT in the select statement (before attribute customID), DISTINCT is less efficent than GROUP_BY.